# How to implement %0.7f in annotation.coordinate?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mkannotation, type-conversion

**I have two strings which hold values say for ex:35.5044752 97.3955550**

Let me convert it :

```
    double f1=[la doubleValue];
    double f2=[lo doubleValue];
```

(value of f1 and f2 is dynamic say for example f1= "35.5044752" f2="97.3955550" )

**if i want to print it in NSLog i will do as follows :**

```
 NSLog(@" %f  %f ",f1,f2);
```

And it returns 35.504475 97.395555

**hence i change it as**

```
NSLog(@" %0.7f  %0.7f ",f1,f2);
```

And gets the full values like  35.5044752 97.3955550

**Now i need it to use in the Coordinate like below:**

```
annotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord.longitude, coord.longitude);
```

**My Question is how can i implement %0.7f here like which i made in NSlog ?**

*so that i should take input fully instead of reducing or altering the value.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a try like this. Directly pass values to obj `center`

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
...
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Lat"]) {
    center.latitude = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"degrees"] doubleValue];
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Lon"]) {
    center.longitude = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"degrees"] doubleValue];
}
...
```

OR

Archived the coordinate in foundLocation:

```
NSNumber *latitudeObject = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coord.latitude];
NSNumber *longitudeObject = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:coord.longitude];
NSArray *coordinateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:latitudeObject, longitudeObject, nil];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:coordinateArray] 
                                          forKey:WhereamiCoordinatePrefKey];
```

Unarchived the coordinate in viewDidLoad:

```
NSArray *coordinateArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                                                                       objectForKey:WhereamiCoordinatePrefKey]];

CLLocationCoordinate2D savedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[coordinateArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue], 
                                                                    [[coordinateArray objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue]);

MKCoordinateRegion savedRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(savedCoordinate, 250, 250);
[worldView setRegion:savedRegion animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%0.7f` format specifier deals with how your value is *displayed*, not with how it is *stored*. A `double` is always `double` and has its inherent precision and nothing you can do, short of casting it to another data type, will change that.

As far as I know, the `double` data type offers the highest floating point precision of the standard data types. If you need greater precision than that, you're going to have to use something other than a `double`.

In other words, when you perform an operation on a `double`, it is always calculated to the full precision allowed by the `double` data type.

For more information on the subject, see the [Wikipedia entry on floating point data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).

Comment: can you please explain ? use a double in the sense ? I have converted it to double only.